# Declaring var in an unray expression?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Let's say I have this :

`$(obj).attr("style","...top:"+________)`

now suppose the `top` is calculated:

`(o.outerHeight(true)>=30?o.outerHeight(true)+'px':'-5px')`

*My* problem is the repeating `o.outerHeight(true)`

*for simplicty* : I know I can do  in general :

`((a=5)>2?a:-1) //5` -- *notice that `a`'s calculation is not repeated.*

but this creates a global `a` variable. (and I *don't* want to do that)

`window.a //5`

I tried :

`((var a=5)>2?a:-1)` *//error  : Unexpected token var

Is there any way *(except declaring my own var)* to avoid this repetition ?

Comment: Why do you try to squeeze that in a single line/statement at all?

Comment: Can you try to calculate outerHeight before attr(): `var n = o.outerHeight(true); (n >= 30) ? n + 'px' : '-5px'`

Comment: @ThiefMaster For learning deeper JS. 
Not everything got to have a special reason.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use an [iife](http://benalman.com/news/2010/11/immediately-invoked-function-expression/):

```
(function(value) { return complex_expression_using_value; }(some_expression))
```

That way, you create a formal function parameter rather than a var. No namespace pollution.

To apply it to your specific example:

```
var top = (function(value) {
        return (value >= 30 ? value : -5) + 'px';
    }(o.outerHeight(true)));
```

Alternatively, you can use the iife as part of another expression:

```
$(obj).attr("style","...top:"+
    (function(value) {
            return (value >= 30 ? value : -5) + 'px';
        }(o.outerHeight(true)))
)
```

Comment: +1 for offering a solution instead of just explaining the problem like I did!

Comment: the `var top` at your second example is exactly what i wanted to avoid.

Comment: @RoyiNamir - You don't need to declare a `var`. That was just to show one way to use the iife. The entire parenthesized iife can be used wherever you would use any other expression. I've appended another example to my answer.

Answer (score 2):

No, since `var a` is a statement, and the conditional (ternary) operator can only take expressions as its operands, according to the [language grammar](http://es5.github.com/#x11.12):

> *ConditionalExpression* :
>       *LogicalORExpression*
>       *LogicalORExpression* `?` *AssignmentExpression* `:` *AssignmentExpression*

You would have to declare the variable beforehand.